# merge N lists to be together by index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 4 lists, i want them to be like the result

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['e', 'f', 'g']
['h', 'i']
['j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']

result --> ['aehj'], ['bfik'], ['cgl'], ['dm'], ['n']
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with a fill value of `''` like so

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
b = ['e', 'f', 'g']
c = ['h', 'i']
d = ['j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']


result = [[''.join(i)] for i in zip_longest(a, b, c, d, fillvalue='')]
print(result)
```

will give

```
[['aehj'], ['bfik'], ['cgl'], ['dm'], ['n']]
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure python

```py
lists = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  ['e', 'f', 'g'],
  ['h', 'i'],
  ['j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n'],
]
results = []
for i in range(0, max(map(len, lists))):
    result = list(map(lambda list: list[i] if i < len(list) else "", lists))
    results.append( "".join(result) )

print(results)
['aehj', 'bfik', 'cgl', 'dm', 'n']
```

Comment: I just want to know the one line trick :)

Comment: ```[ "".join(map(lambda list: list[i] if i < len(list) else "", lists)) for i in range(0, max(map(len, lists))) ]```